# Trying to refactor the recursive query in an Oracle CTE?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have been working on a CTE which works pretty good for MS-SQL.  I am translating it to Oracle and it works.  However it is very slow and when I look at the explain plan I see "Merge Join Cartesian" when I run the query.  I am running against Oracle 12.2. If I remove the

> "OR" (...)

part of the query the speed is dramatically improved.  However the "Merge Join Cartesian" still shows up in the explain plan.  I have determined where the problem is in the query.  The

> "and" (....) "or" (...)

in the recursive query is the source of the slowness.  I need both sections because there are different paths so getting rid of one or the other is not really an option.  I have tried to rewrite that part of CTE but I am not having much luck.  My first try was to include a second query in the recursive section.  However Oracle ONLY allows one query in the recursive section of the CTE.  I have also tried to break this down into smaller pieces but my attempts have failed.  I would appreciate any suggestions on rewriting the recursive section in this CTE.

```
AND
    (    
        myCTE3.SubWorkflowBaseId <>  '0000000000000000' 
        and myCTE3.SubWorkflowBaseId is not null 
        and myCTE3.JoinColumn = wfb.WorkflowBaseId
        and wfb.RevOfRcdId    = wf.WorkflowId
        and wf.workflowid     = wfs.WorkflowId
    )       
OR
    (
        myCTE3.SubWorkflowId <>  '0000000000000000'
        and myCTE3.SubWorkflowId is not null 
        and myCTE3.JoinColumn =  wf.workflowid 
        --and wf.workflowid     = wfs.SubWorkflowId
        and wf.workflowid     = wfs.WorkflowId
  and wf.WorkflowBaseId = wfb.WorkflowBaseId     
    )
```

I have posted my CTE and sample data on SQLFiddle.  I forgot to post the expected results with my initial post.  The order the records should come back is the following.  There are steps in a workflow which point to subworkflow but those should be excluded from the results.

Step-1a -> Step-2a -> Step-3a -> Step-3b -> Step-1c.

[Sample Data and CTE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/708c28/1)

```
Plan hash value: 3402776882

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |               |     2 |  4074 |    76   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                             |               |     2 |  4074 |    76   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   VIEW                                     |               |     2 |  4074 |    75   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    UNION ALL (RECURSIVE WITH) BREADTH FIRST|               |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                              |               |     1 |   119 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | WORKFLOWSTEP2 |     1 |   102 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | WORKFLOW2     |     1 |    17 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |               |     1 |  2239 |    69   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |      BUFFER SORT (REUSE)                   |               |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |       MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                 |               |     1 |   170 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |        MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                |               |     1 |   136 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | WORKFLOWSTEP2 |     1 |   102 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |         BUFFER SORT                        |               |     3 |   102 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | WORKFLOWBASE2 |     3 |   102 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |        BUFFER SORT                         |               |     3 |   102 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | WORKFLOW2     |     3 |   102 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |      RECURSIVE WITH PUMP                   |               |       |       |            |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("MYCTE3"."STEPTYPE"<>2)
   4 - access("WF"."WORKFLOWID"="WFS"."WORKFLOWID")
   5 - filter("WFS"."WORKFLOWID"='1100000000000000')
   6 - filter("WF"."WORKFLOWID"='1100000000000000')
  16 - filter("MYCTE3"."JOINCOLUMN" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "MYCTE3"."SUBWORKFLOWBASEID"<>'0000000000000000' AND "MYCTE3"."SUBWORKFLOWBASEID" IS NOT NULL AND 
              "MYCTE3"."JOINCOLUMN"="WFB"."WORKFLOWBASEID" AND "WFB"."REVOFRCDID"="WF"."WORKFLOWID" AND 
              "WF"."WORKFLOWID"="WFS"."WORKFLOWID" OR "MYCTE3"."SUBWORKFLOWID"<>'0000000000000000' AND 
              "MYCTE3"."SUBWORKFLOWID" IS NOT NULL AND "MYCTE3"."JOINCOLUMN"="WF"."WORKFLOWID" AND 
              "WF"."WORKFLOWID"="WFS"."WORKFLOWID" AND "WF"."WORKFLOWBASEID"="WFB"."WORKFLOWBASEID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to rewrite is as:

```
with MyCTE3 (WorkflowStepName, Depth, WorkflowId, WorkflowStepId, SubWorkflowBaseId, SubWorkflowId, Sequence, StepType, JoinColumn, DisplayOrder) as 
(
    SELECT wfs.WorkflowStepName
           ,1 as Depth
           , wfs.WorkflowId
           , wfs.WorkflowStepId
           , wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
           , wfs.SubWorkflowId
           , wfs.Sequence
           , wfs.StepType
           , case 
                when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubworkflowId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId is null then wfs.SubworkflowId
                when wfs.SubWorkflowId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowId is null then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
             end as JoinColumn
          ,1 || '.' || CAST(wfs.Sequence AS VARCHAR(255))  AS DisplayOrder
      --, to_clob(wfs.WorkflowId) as ProcessedWorkflow
      FROM WorkflowStep2 wfs, Workflow2  wf 
     WHERE wfs.WorkflowId = '1100000000000000' 
     and wf.WorkflowId = wfs.WorkflowId

    union all
    SELECT wfs.WorkflowStepName
            ,  Depth+1
            , wfs.WorkflowId
            , wfs.WorkflowStepId
            , wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
            , wfs.SubWorkflowId
            , wfs.Sequence
            , wfs.StepType
            , case 
                when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubworkflowId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId is null then wfs.SubworkflowId
                when wfs.SubWorkflowId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowId is null then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
                end as JoinColumn
        ,DisplayOrder || '.' || CAST(Depth+1 AS VARCHAR(255)) || CAST(wfs.Sequence AS VARCHAR(255))  as DisplayOrder
        --,to_clob(myCTE3.ProcessedWorkflow) || ',' || to_clob(wfs.WorkflowId) as ProcessedWorkflow
        FROM workflowbase2 wfb, workflowstep2 wfs, workflow2 wf, MyCTE3     
    where  myCTE3.JoinColumn is not null
    -- and (','+to_clob(myCTE3.ProcessedWorkflow) +',' not like '%,'+to_clob(wfs.WorkflowId)+',%')    
    -- and (dbms_lob.instr(myCTE3.ProcessedWorkflow,wfs.WorkflowId) = 0)  
        AND
        (    
            myCTE3.SubWorkflowBaseId <>  '0000000000000000' 
            and myCTE3.SubWorkflowBaseId is not null 
            and myCTE3.JoinColumn = wfb.WorkflowBaseId
            and wfb.RevOfRcdId    = wf.WorkflowId
            and wf.workflowid     = wfs.WorkflowId
        )   
), mcte2(WorkflowStepName, Depth, WorkflowId, WorkflowStepId, SubWorkflowBaseId, SubWorkflowId, Sequence, StepType, JoinColumn, DisplayOrder) AS (
  SELECT wfs.WorkflowStepName
           ,1 as Depth
           , wfs.WorkflowId
           , wfs.WorkflowStepId
           , wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
           , wfs.SubWorkflowId
           , wfs.Sequence
           , wfs.StepType
           , case 
                when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubworkflowId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId is null then wfs.SubworkflowId
                when wfs.SubWorkflowId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowId is null then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
             end as JoinColumn
          ,1 || '.' || CAST(wfs.Sequence AS VARCHAR(255))  AS DisplayOrder
      --, to_clob(wfs.WorkflowId) as ProcessedWorkflow
      FROM WorkflowStep2 wfs, Workflow2  wf 
     WHERE wfs.WorkflowId = '1100000000000000' 
     and wf.WorkflowId = wfs.WorkflowId

    union all


  SELECT wfs.WorkflowStepName
            ,  Depth+1
            , wfs.WorkflowId
            , wfs.WorkflowStepId
            , wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
            , wfs.SubWorkflowId
            , wfs.Sequence
            , wfs.StepType
            , case 
                when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubworkflowId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId is null then wfs.SubworkflowId
                when wfs.SubWorkflowId = '0000000000000000' then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
                --when wfs.SubWorkflowId is null then wfs.SubWorkflowBaseId
                end as JoinColumn
        ,DisplayOrder || '.' || CAST(Depth+1 AS VARCHAR(255)) || CAST(wfs.Sequence AS VARCHAR(255))  as DisplayOrder
        --,to_clob(myCTE3.ProcessedWorkflow) || ',' || to_clob(wfs.WorkflowId) as ProcessedWorkflow
        FROM workflowbase2 wfb, workflowstep2 wfs, workflow2 wf, MyCTE3     
    where  myCTE3.JoinColumn is not null
       AND
        (
            myCTE3.SubWorkflowId <>  '0000000000000000'
            and myCTE3.SubWorkflowId is not null 
            and myCTE3.JoinColumn =  wf.workflowid 
            --and wf.workflowid     = wfs.SubWorkflowId
            and wf.workflowid     = wfs.WorkflowId
      and wf.WorkflowBaseId = wfb.WorkflowBaseId     
        ) 
)
select   WorkFlowStepName, DisplayOrder --, DisplayOrder, ProcessedWorkflow
  from MyCTE3
where MYCTE3.StepType <> 2
UNION ALL
select   WorkFlowStepName, DisplayOrder --, DisplayOrder, ProcessedWorkflow
  from MyCTE3
where MYCTE3.StepType <> 2
order by DisplayOrder ;
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/708c28/5/0)**

I've used [OR expansion](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion)

> OR expansion is a transformation that can be used to optimize disjunctive queries (queries that contain OR clauses). The basic idea in OR expansion is to transform a query containing disjunctions into the form of a UNION ALL query of two or more branches. This is done by splitting the disjunction into its components and associating each component with a branch of a UNION ALL query.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about OR expansion.  I will investigate and see if it helps.  Right now the results set includes duplicates and does not appear to drill down into the result set.  It was my fault, I forgot to post the expected results with my post.  I updated the post with that information.  I will take a look at your example and see if I can make something work.   I will post back what I find out.  Again, thanks for the effort and idea.

Comment: I think I see what you are doing.  The "And (...) Or(...)" are linked.  In other words in the recursive query either the "And (...)" is executed or the "OR (...)" is executed not both.  However I will not know which path is executed until the query looks at the steps in the resultset.  WorkflowStep has two columns, SubWorkflowBaseId and SubWorkflowId.  As the query is drilling down it will pick the "And (...) aka SubWorkflowBaseId if it has a valid value or "OR (...)" SubWorkflowId if it has a valid value and will continue to loop until no more records are found that match.