# Conditional WHERE EXISTS in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle here. I have the following table:

```
create table Foobars ( 
    id integer constraint pkFoobars primary key using index,
    fizz varchar2(20 char), 
    buzz varchar2(20 char)
)
```

In my code I will be given a string called `fizzOrBuzz`, and I will not know which field (`fizz` or `buzz`) it will be ahead of time. I need to search the `Foobars` table for *either* a matching `fizz` or `buzz` based on the `fizzOrBuzz` value. The only thing that is certain is that there are no duplicates (no 2 records will have the same `fizz` value, and no 2 records will have the same `buzz` value).

My query thus far:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  Foobars
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    Foobars
  WHERE
    fizz = ? -- fizzOrBuzz gets injected here by the app layer
) OR (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    Foobars
  WHERE
    buzz = ? -- fizzOrBuzz gets injected here by the app layer  
)
```

However this isn't valid SQL code (doesn't execute) and I'm sure there's a better way of doing this altogether. Any ideas?

Comment: `OR` => `OR EXISTS` ? But the other options offered as answers are be better; not least because your subqueries aren't correlated - assuming you're expecting the ID from those to match the main query. (It's helpful to show the error you got, and sample data/expected results.)

Comment: Does the fizz column actually contain the string "fizz"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `exists`, surely a basic `or` works here:

```
select id
from   foobars
where  fizz = ? -- fizzOrBuzz gets injected here by the app layer
or     buzz = ? -- fizzOrBuzz gets injected here by the app layer
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use `OR`?

```
select id
from foobars
where fizz = ? or buzz = ?;
```

Or, just use one parameter with `IN`:

```
select id
from foobars
where ? in (fizz, buzz);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `UNION`:

```
SELECT id FROM Foobars WHERE fizz = ?
UNION 
SELECT id FROM Foobars WHERE buzz = ?
```

Comment: Writing query in this manner in Oracle does not make sense. You might want to read about Oracle query transformations and OR-expansion in particular.

Comment: @DrYWit . . . You should be a little more informative with such a comment.  Is the issue the `UNION`?  Would it be fixed by using `UNION ALL`?  Are you assuming there are indexes on the `fizz` and `buzz` columns?

Comment: @DrYWit The query itself is perfectly valid and I know what a [OR-expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929220/5070879) is. Please note I am using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, if someone uses OR then CBO can transform a query to the form which is more efficient based on statistics, presence of indexes etc. With `UNION` Oracle will always access table twice; not to mention that, yes, UNION ALL must be used instead of UNION. And for those who are interested: https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, the query you provide does not have any advantage in compare to version with 'OR' but has a number of drawbacks instead and should never be recommended even though it's "perfectly valid". I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `OR`

```
SELECT id FROM Foobars WHERE fizz = ? OR buzz = ?
```

Cheers!!